# Firewall stuck on expand

Tags: group-policy, windows-firewall, winrm

Ive been having some issues trying to open the Windows Firewall Advanced.
It just gets stuck with a "expand" window:

[expand image](https://image.prntscr.com/image/IgdhclcwSdOJ8h7ISTns9A.png)

Ive been searching a lot on google trying to debug this.

If i run a `gpresult -z` i get a Access Denied, which would seem that there is some permissions issues. Same for `gpupdate /force`.

Ive tried to run `winmgmt /verifyrepository` and `winmgmt /salvagerepository` both also gives me a Access denied.

The firewall gpo has been working fine for a couple of years, but one of our IT guys decided to setup WinRM and might have changed some permissions.

It seems to not only to apply to the Firewall but other snap-in's also fail aswell. If I open the Component Services, the whole mmc will freeze forever.

Does anybody have experience with this? What do i need to look for? Cause I've been looking at all the polices we have atm, but it doesn't look like any of those could mess up this bad.

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue, came here to post this

Comment: We found out that something as simple as a powershell script to install different software, including Microsoft Office Deployment setup caused everything to hold all calls. The way we found out was actually really simple, we saw that there was a powershell script running in our taskmanager when it shoudnt be there. So we just as a test disabled all of our installations scripts, and what do you know everything worked again.